# Python: pip install sublime not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, sublimetext3

I am considerably new to both sublime. However, I really enjoy that one may add lots of feature to sublime using python code. I always do my python on Jupyter notebook. I usually install modules as easy through Anaconda i.e. `!pip install sublime`

I actually coded the following on my jupyter notebook

```
!pip install sublime
```

the outcome:

```
Collecting sublime
  Downloading sublime-0.1.0.tar.gz
Collecting click<4.0,>=3.3 (from sublime)
  Downloading click-3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: sublime
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for sublime: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for sublime: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\Rami New\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\03\a6\f1\a6f87bcdcdc1cd6074dae417ff91fa39039ad0c2c1133898ff
Successfully built sublime
Installing collected packages: click, sublime
  Found existing installation: click 6.7
    Uninstalling click-6.7:
      Successfully uninstalled click-6.7
Successfully installed click-3.3 sublime-0.1.0
```

when I code

```
import sublime
```

an error turn as

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-b083c915bef9> in <module>()
----> 1 import sublime

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sublime'
```

May anyone help me through getting across this?

Comment: Have you tried to restart the kernel or jupyter notebook?

Comment: yes but still same problem!

Comment: Have you tired out to install it as a user? `pip install sublime --user`

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: sublime in c:\users\rami new\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: click<4.0,>=3.3 in c:\users\rami new\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from sublime)

Comment: @Nils still did not work

Comment: Try out `pip3` - maybe that's your fault

Comment: Or install trough anaconda `conda install sublime`

Comment: No success still :s