# Sublime Text and Python plugin: How to incorporate a python code with a for loop in sublime text editor

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I am relatively new to using python scripts as plugins in Sublime Text (Note: I am not a developer). However, I am in a situation in which I always end up with the same certain events and I need to automate some operations on a string through a script.

For example, suppose I have the following values in a text file:

```
@article{jentsch2010multiple,
      title={The multiple hybrid bootstrap—Resampling multivariate linear processes},
      author={Jentsch, Carsten and Kreiss, Jens-Peter},
      journal={Journal of Multivariate Analysis},
      volume={101},
      number={10},
      pages={2320--2345},
      year={2010},
      publisher={Elsevier}
    }

    @article{buhlmann1997sieve,
      title={Sieve bootstrap for time series},
      author={B{\"u}hlmann, Peter},
      journal={Bernoulli},
      volume={3},
      number={2},
      pages={123--148},
      year={1997},
      publisher={Bernoulli Society for Mathematical Statistics and Probability}
    }


@article{kreiss2011bootstrap,
  title={Bootstrap methods for dependent data: A review},
  author={Kreiss, Jens-Peter and Paparoditis, Efstathios},
  journal={Journal of the Korean Statistical Society},
  volume={40},
  number={4},
  pages={357--378},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

What I want is to make each in a line i.e.

```
@article{jentsch2010multiple,   title={The multiple hybrid bootstrap—Resampling multivariate linear processes},   author={Jentsch, Carsten and Kreiss, Jens-Peter},   journal={Journal of Multivariate Analysis},   volume={101},   number={10},   pages={2320--2345},   year={2010},   publisher={Elsevier} }
@article{buhlmann1997sieve,   title={Sieve bootstrap for time series},   author={B{"u}hlmann, Peter},   journal={Bernoulli},   volume={3},   number={2},   pages={123--148},   year={1997},   publisher={Bernoulli Society for Mathematical Statistics and Probability} }
@article{kreiss2011bootstrap,   title={Bootstrap methods for dependent data: A review},   author={Kreiss, Jens-Peter and Paparoditis, Efstathios},   journal={Journal of the Korean Statistical Society},   volume={40},   number={4},   pages={357--378},   year={2011},   publisher={Elsevier} }
```

Currently, what I do is that I copy everything to the text editor (i.e. Sublime Text 3) and then I paste it in as a string value in Python to execute the code.

Here's what I have:

```
A='''
@article{jentsch2010multiple,
  title={The multiple hybrid bootstrap—Resampling multivariate linear processes},
  author={Jentsch, Carsten and Kreiss, Jens-Peter},
  journal={Journal of Multivariate Analysis},
  volume={101},
  number={10},
  pages={2320--2345},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{buhlmann1997sieve,
  title={Sieve bootstrap for time series},
  author={B{\"u}hlmann, Peter},
  journal={Bernoulli},
  volume={3},
  number={2},
  pages={123--148},
  year={1997},
  publisher={Bernoulli Society for Mathematical Statistics and Probability}
}

@article{kreiss2011bootstrap,
  title={Bootstrap methods for dependent data: A review},
  author={Kreiss, Jens-Peter and Paparoditis, Efstathios},
  journal={Journal of the Korean Statistical Society},
  volume={40},
  number={4},
  pages={357--378},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
'''

print(
    '\n'.join(
        [' '.join(para.splitlines()) for para in A.split('\n\n')]
    )
)
```

However, I noticed it is possible to do all of this in Sublime Text so I do not have to copy and past the entire string and then execute the script.

The link is [here](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/plugins.html). However, the link says explicitly that documentation on this topic is scarce. Can someone help me with this?

All I know so far about the topic is the following procedure:

1) Select Tools | Developer | New Plugin in the menu.
This will open the following:

```
 import sublime
    import sublime_plugin


    class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
        def run(self, edit):
            self.view.insert(edit, 0, "Hello, World!")
```

2. How could I adjust this code to add my code?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the following plugin as mentioned in the question i.e. `Tools ---> Developer ---> New Plugin ...` and save it any name you wish with .py at the very end.

**Plugin**:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, re, string   #import the required modules

class ConvertCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand): #create Text Command
    def run(self, edit):   #implement run method
        for region in self.view.sel():  #get user selection
            if not region.empty():  #if selection not empty then
                s = self.view.substr(region)  #assign s variable the selected region
                replace = '\n'.join([' '.join(para.splitlines()) for para in s.split('\n\n')])
                self.view.replace(edit, region, replace) #replace content in view


class UndoCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand): #create Text Command
    def run(self, edit):   #implement run method
        for region in self.view.sel():  #get user selection
            if not region.empty():  #if selection not empty then
                s = self.view.substr(region)  #assign s variable the selected region
                replace = '\n'.split([' '.join(para.splitlines()) for para in s.split('\n\n')])
                self.view.replace(edit, region, replace) #replace content in view
```

This has created a new `command` called `Convert` and `Undo`

## Menu view

Then create a sublime-menu that will create a new command called `convert` this is saved as the id name

Remark: SUBLIME-MENU files are used to control the main and context menu in Sublime Text.

**Menu:** Save as `context.sublime-menu`

```
[
{ 
    "caption": "Convert", 
    "id": "convert", 
    "children":
    [
    {
    "caption": "Convert",
    "command": "convert"
    },
    {
    "caption": "Undo Convert",
    "command": "undo"
    }
    ]
}
]
```

[image: Select the text -> Right Click Convert]

## Keybindings

```
Preferences ---> Key Bindings
```

Then write this

```
[
{"keys": ["alt+enter"], "command": "convert"},
]
```

This will allow you to select and simply press on your keyboard `alt+enter` will allow you to do the task.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I really appreciate your help but may you let me know how exactly this is done. So I save the first code as a .py (does it require any special name?) then I save it then how do I do the menu ? I am sorry for all these questions but I am new and I can not find online things that teach us how to do so and I can not import sublime in my jupyter editor.

Comment: No special name is needed for the plugin, just save it in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/convert.py. menu **should** be saved as context.sublime-menu in the same path

Comment: thank you so much mate! How can I learn this? The reason for my question is that I am finding my self always asking questions on this topic and I can not know how to import sublime to an editor to learn how sublime text uses the commands see my unanswered question on this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49200465/python-pip-install-sublime-not-working

Comment: For example, can I do it as a key bindings instead of a menu?

Comment: Yes, just create this file instead of menu http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html